# IServiceProvider not available in .NET Standard?

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I'm trying to convert a PCL to .NET Standard 1.3 and failing.  I've narrowed the failure down to a really simple example that I can't understand why it's failing.

I have a class that implements `IMarkupExtension` and simply compiling a project with just that class fails with:

> The type 'IServiceProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Why on earth is it trying to pull in `System.ComponentModel` for a Xamarin Forms library that's using .NET Standard?  It makes no sense to me.

The project references are as simple as you can get:

[image]

The class implementation couldn't be any simpler:

```
namespace OpenNETCF
{
    public sealed class ScaledDouble : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I can get rid of the compiler error by manually editing the project file to include `System.ComponentModel`, but unsurprisingly the consuming app fails to load the type at runtime.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.3.4.267" />

    <!-- Required for IMarkupExtension and IServiceProvider to compile.  No idea why. -->
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What's going on here??

Comment: Hmm, these are Silverlight interfaces.  Check the [compatibility chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support).  Silverlight is dead technology, development stopped in 2013.

Comment: Did you try installing [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel/)?

Answer (score 1):

.NET Standard  projects doesn't have default assemblies. You should add reference or download from nuget.

> PM> Install-Package System.ComponentModel